# Conditions to paginate for belongsToMany CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the tables Semesters, Disciplines and a jointTable Semesters_Disciplines. I want to create a action index in DisciplinesController with a semester_id as parameter, which list with paginate just the disciplines what belongs to the semester with the id passed in the parameter. I tried this:

```
public function index($semester_id)
{
    $options = ['semester_id' => $semester_id];
    $this->paginate = ['conditions' => $options];

    $this->set('disciplines', $this->paginate($this->Disciplines));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['disciplines']);
}
```

Comment: What were the results of your test, and what occurred that you were or were not expecting?

Comment: Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'semesters_id' in 'where clause'

Well...the 'conditions' just accept a condition related with the model of the controller...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll have to use a query that uses matching or joins to be able to filter on non `1:1`/`n-1` associations.

You can do so by either passing a query directly to the `paginate()` method

```
// ...
$this->set('disciplines', $this->paginate(
    $this->Disciplines
        ->find()
        ->matching('Semesters', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) use ($semester_id) {
            return $q->where([
                'Semesters.id' => $semester_id
            ]);
        })
        ->group(['Disciplines.id'])
));
// ...
```

or by using a custom finder.

```
// ...
$this->paginate = [
    'finder' => [
        'semesters' => [
            'semester_id' => $semester_id
        ]
    ]
];
$this->set('disciplines', $this->paginate($this->Disciplines));
// ...
```

```
// DisciplinesTable
public function findSemesters(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
        ->matching('Semesters', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) use ($options) {
            return $q->where([
                'Semesters.id' => $options['semester_id']
            ]);
        })
        ->group(['Disciplines.id']);
    return $query;
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Pagination > Using Controller::paginate()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate)**
- **[Cookbook > Retrieving Data and Result Sets > Custom Finder Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-find-methods)**
- **[Cookbook > QueryBuilder > Filtering by Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**
- **[Cookbook > QueryBuilder > Adding Joins](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)**